# When installing octobercms project in terminal I get this error: Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages

Tags: php, laravel, terminal, composer-php, octobercms

I am trying to install octobercms in the terminal. The documentation is pretty straight forward and easy to follow but when I try and create the project by typing:

```
composer create-project october/october myoctober dev-master
```

I get this error:

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - laravel/framework v5.0.9 requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.0.8 requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.0.7 requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.0.6 requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.0.5 requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.0.4 requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.0.34 requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.0.33 requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.0.32 requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.0.31 requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.0.3 requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.0.29 requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.0.28 requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.0.27 requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.0.26 requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.0.25 requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.0.24 requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.0.23 requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.0.22 requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.0.21 requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.0.20 requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.0.2 requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.0.19 requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.0.18 requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.0.17 requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.0.16 requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.0.15 requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.0.14 requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.0.13 requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.0.12 requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.0.11 requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.0.10 requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.0.1 requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework v5.0.0 requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework 5.0.x-dev requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system.
    - laravel/framework 5.0.30 requires ext-mcrypt * -> the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system.
    - Installation request for laravel/framework 5.0.* -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[5.0.30, 5.0.x-dev, v5.0.0, v5.0.1, v5.0.10, v5.0.11, v5.0.12, v5.0.13, v5.0.14, v5.0.15, v5.0.16, v5.0.17, v5.0.18, v5.0.19, v5.0.2, v5.0.20, v5.0.21, v5.0.22, v5.0.23, v5.0.24, v5.0.25, v5.0.26, v5.0.27, v5.0.28, v5.0.29, v5.0.3, v5.0.31, v5.0.32, v5.0.33, v5.0.34, v5.0.4, v5.0.5, v5.0.6, v5.0.7, v5.0.8, v5.0.9].
```

It still makes the folder but I don't know how solve this. No one else seems to be having this issue with october. any help would be appreciated!

```
{
        "name": "october/october",
        "description": "October CMS",
        "homepage": "http://octobercms.com",
        "keywords": ["october", "cms", "octobercms", "laravel"],
        "license": "MIT",
        "authors": [
            {
                "name": "Alexey Bobkov",
                "email": "aleksey.bobkov@gmail.com",
                "role": "Co-founder"
            },
            {
                "name": "Samuel Georges",
                "email": "daftspunky@gmail.com",
                "role": "Co-founder"
            }
        ],
        "support": {
            "issues": "https://github.com/octobercms/october/issues",
            "forum": "http://octobercms.com/forum/",
            "docs": "http://octobercms.com/docs/",
            "irc": "irc://irc.freenode.net/october",
            "source": "https://github.com/octobercms/october"
        },
        "require": {
            "php": ">=5.4",
            "october/rain": "~1.0",
            "october/system": "~1.0",
            "october/backend": "~1.0",
            "october/cms": "~1.0",
            "laravel/framework": "5.0.*",
            "illuminate/html": "5.0.*"
        },
        "require-dev": {
            "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.0",
            "phpunit/phpunit-selenium": ">=1.2"
        },
        "autoload-dev": {
            "classmap": [
                "tests/TestCase.php",
                "tests/UiTestCase.php",
                "tests/PluginTestCase.php"
            ]
        },
        "scripts": {
            "post-create-project-cmd": [
                "php artisan key:generate"
            ]
        },
        "config": {
            "preferred-install": "dist"
        },
        "minimum-stability": "dev",
        "prefer-stable": true
    }
```

Comment: I understand your question, but if you can read the error, _the requested PHP extension mcrypt is missing from your system._ said all. Please read the error and then find a solution.

Answer (score 2):

You should install `mcrypt` extension for PHP.

For Debian based systems:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-mcrypt
```

For Mac OS X:

```
brew install mcrypt php56-mcrypt
```

Comment: Since the OP didn't specify the OS, you should specify that this solution is for Debian based systems like Ubuntu.

Comment: I am on mac. My terminal doesn't seem to recognize the command apt-get

Comment: @derg If you have `brew` installed then you can run `brew install mcrypt php56-mcrypt` on OS X.

Comment: @Bogdan thanks for that clarification, I've updated my answer.

Comment: It's working! @bogdan. You are amazing!!!!! I have literally sent so long trying to figure this out! Thank you!!